# code throws me an error: Space is an illegal character after a colon.

Tags: lisp

sort code, which is basically a translation i made from this one:

```
insertion(A)
  for i from 2 to n
      j=i-1
      while (j>=1) AND (A[j]>A[j+1])do
         t=A[j+1]
         A[j+1]=A[j]
         A[j]=t
         j=j-1
```

and my translation to lisp is

```
(defun insertion (unsorted-vector)
  (let ((vector (copy-seq unsorted-vector))
        (n (length unsorted-vector)))
    (loop :for i : from 2: below (n)
      :do ((j (- i 1))
        (loop :do (AND (>= (j 1))
                       (> (aref vector j) (aref vector (+ j 1))))
                  (rotatef (aref vector j) (aref vector (+ j 1))) 
                  (j (- j 1))))
    vector)))

(insertion #(5 1 3 2))
```

but it is throwing me a message that says: Error while reading: #\Space is an illegal character after a colon. and i don´t understand what does it mean, and don´t know if there are any other mistakes in the code.

Comment: There are many other problems here: `n` is not a function, `j` is not a function, `j` is undefined, you never seem to use the return value of your `and` form.  Don't try to do syntactic translation, try to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is space. Look at your code, you should write `:from` or just `from`, not `: from`, and the same thing with `below`.

```
(defun insertion (unsorted-vector)
  (let ((vector (copy-seq unsorted-vector))
        (n (length unsorted-vector)))
    (loop :for i : from 2: below (n) ;; your problem
;;;             ^^^     ^^^          ;; <= is here
;;; Change to :from and :below 
      :do ((j (- i 1))
        (loop :do (AND (>= (j 1))
                       (> (aref vector j) (aref vector (+ j 1))))
                  (rotatef (aref vector j) (aref vector (+ j 1))) 
                  (j (- j 1))))
    vector)))
```

Comment: That was pretty much what I intended to say (in my now-deleted answer), but I don't think `loop`'s syntax (in Common Lisp, at least; the OP didn't say what dialect they're using) uses keywords.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: you can use a symbol from any package - even the keyword package. CL only looks at the name for LOOP keywords, not at the package. This is fine:  `(loop foo::for i :in '(1 2 3) bar::do (print i))` , given that FOO and BAR are packages. The error thus was anyway not in the LOOP, but the s-expression was already wrong.

Comment: @Rainer Thanks! Learnt something new today. Still I'd say that seeing them as keywords or alternative package symbols seems unidiomatic.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: keywords in LOOP statements are not that rare in new code (last ten years ;-) ). It used to be rare in older code. I don't use them, but I'm old. ;-)