# "illegal terminating character after a colon: #\" in portacle, though no colons in code

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I've recently set up Portacle 1.3 for learning common lisp on Win 7. However, whenever I run my code I get the error, even if there is no code.
Running individual lines works fine, however. The error only shows when I run the whole file.

I tried putting some code in an EVAL function, but I believe that only accepts one argument at a time, so I couldn't run a whole program in it.

I've found a similar error in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858520/code-throws-me-an-error-space-is-an-illegal-character-after-a-colon) stackoverflow page, but their code contains colons and that's where their error lies.

I think it might be an error in the code that runs mine, seeing as I get the error even if I compile with no code, however I know nothing.

The full error:

```
main.lisp:1:1:
  read-error: 
    READ error during COMPILE-FILE:

      illegal terminating character after a colon: #\

        Line: 1, Column: 13, File-Position: 12

        Stream: #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file [path to file]\\main.lisp" {1005F5F0D3}>

Compilation failed.
```

Comment: We can't help without code. Also there is all information you need in this error message `Line: 1, Column: 13, File-Position: 12` - what is at this position?

Comment: There is no need for code. My code has no relevance. I should have stated it better - The error persists even if I compile with no code written. If I start a lisp document and immediately compile, the error shows exactly the same.

Comment: OK, what do you mean by *"start a lisp document"*? You mean you get this error even with empty (zero bytes) file?

Comment: And how do you compile your code? Do you use REPL/Slime? Or you write your file and compile using CLI? We still need more info, help us to help you, we are no borg, we don't know what you do.

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience. I wasn't completely sure what to put. Yes, compiling a blank document - zero bytes - gets this error.

Comment: To compile, I use the commands C-c C-c for single line compilation, and C-c C-k to compile it all. I found these in the portable help buffer under "COMMON LISP INTERACTION".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Portacle](https://github.com/portacle/portacle) is a standalone Emacs packaged with everything needed for Common Lisp development and which uses SBCL as the Common Lisp implementation.

I believe what you do when you say 'compile the whole file' is call `slime-compile-and-load-file` which is bound to the key sequence `C-c C-k` by default. There are a lot of moving components here:

- [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) is the text editor here. It also takes care of launching all the necessary components for Common Lisp development.
- [Slime](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) is one such component. It serves as interface between Emacs and your Common Lisp implementation (SBCL in this case, but supports any Lisp in theory). Basically it sends the code you wrote in Emacs to your Lisp for evaluation.
- [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) is the Common Lisp implementation. In this case it is a compiler. This is what evaluates the code it receives and spews out the answers to the user interface in Emacs, through Slime. It also 'lives', in the sense that you interact with it by modifying the state of the loaded Lisp image, keeping track of defined functions, global dynamic variables and much more. This is why you can have the REPL, and why you need Slime to interact with it.

So to debug your problem, I would try to:

- Launch SBCL from the Windows shell and run a simple `.lisp` file to check that everything works. You can put for example `(format t "~a" (lisp-implementation-type))` in a `.lisp` file and run it in SBCL from the shell by calling `(load "...\\file.lisp")`. It should return `"SBCL"`.
- Create a completely new file using Emacs (and not weird Windows programs that could mess up the files) (`C-x C-f`), and try to call the compile from there (`C-c C-k`).

And I believe you made the right choice of IDE. Portacle is arguably the simplest tool out there if you are a total beginner in Common Lisp and do not know Emacs configuration. The keybindings are a bit daunting though.

Comment: Thank you! Creating the file from within Portacle worked.